# Google Analytics is not showing all tracking of order

Tags: drupal-7, google-analytics, ubercart

I am running a website and registered for Google Analytics. Got code embedded into my site.

My site in On Drupal and using Ubercart for Online shopping. There is only one payment mode BY CREDIT/DEBIT CARD.

The issue is that Analytics in not tracking my all orders that have been made, some of them is missing.

I have checked that the code has no issues in it, not problem of Sync as well because i have waited a long and orders that are missing are of the date say for example 5-9-2013 and i do have orders tracked of date 6-9-2013.

Anyone have any idea how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User can opt out of the Google Analytics Tracking, they may have not javascript, they may cancel page load before the tag has fired, they may sit an office where the company firewall filters out calls to the google server etc. Javascript-based tracking is never especially accurate (Google themselves warns that Analytics show Trends, not exact numbers).

So I don't think there's a way to resolve differences between GA and backend systems.